# How to export Cisco AnyConnect preferences and certificates to another PC

Tags: windows, vpn, cisco, mac, cisco-vpn

I have two computers (PC and MAC) connected to different organization VPNs. I want to be able to connect from MAC to the same VPNs set on PC. So I need to export VPN list and certificates, etc to my MAC. Is there a way to do it or what do I need to copy manually? Assume everything from:

```
%ProgramData%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile
```

to:

```
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile
```

But how do I properly merge it then? Assume I need to export certificates properly

Answer (score 0):

As you have Cisco Anyconnect,

I don't think you need to move the profile if you know the URL of your VPN.

First, install the [tool](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client-v4-x/model.html#~tab-downloads) on your Mac and simply type the URL of your VPN on the Mac.

[image]

Comment: right, I know the URL.. The problem is that when I try to connect from another laptop it brings an error message "..... invalid certificate... "... So wondering what and how I need to copy to another laptop to be able to make connections

Comment: Can you share me your screenshot?

Comment: I get the same certificate error. http://compit.se/bilder/CiscoAnyConnect/cisco2.PNG There is a button "Get Certificate", but I don't have the one time password provided by admin any more. I would like to just copy the certificate from the one machine to another.

Comment: In that case the issue is with your certificate store and not with Cisco preferences imo. These certs are usually pushed down via Group Policy, so it sounds like you're trying to log in from a private PC, which isn't a good idea.